# Best way to load lots of images without stuttering.

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a site that I load images only when these are in slightly below the view point.

This way, the site first loads without the images then determine what images are needed to be loaded based on the viewpoint.

When user scrolls, and the image is just below the viewpoint, then it loads them.

It works fine on desktop. No laggy, no stutter.

However on mobile web, when I scroll, it stutters as the images are loaded.

Once everything is loaded, the site scrolls up and down smoothly. Also images are resized on the fly to minize file size.

The question that I have is that, what is the best way to load lots of images?

I am loading them only after the site is loaded, then only if they are just bit below the view point.

Do you think I should load them all to avoid stuttering especially on mobile?

I googleed smooth image loading but I don't think I am searching correct terms.

Anyway suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: give your empty imge approriate dimensions before loadding them, that waythe hieght and width of the document aren't changing as the uuser scrolls, which would be much more noticable on  a smaler screen

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple and lightweight JS lazy loader library. It's straight forward and easy to understand.

[BLazy.js](http://dinbror.dk/blazy/)

There is a walk through example from their site.

```
<script src="blazy.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {
        // Initialize
        var bLazy = new Blazy();
    })();
</script>
```

Then in your HTML you would setup your images like this. Give it a `b-lazy` class and a `data-src` attribute that points to the image.

```
<img class="b-lazy" data-src="image.jpg" />
```

[ebLazy.js – A lazyload image script](http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/?ref=demo-page)

[blazy.js examples](http://dinbror.dk/blazy/examples/?ref=blog)